# Why is "url.exist" showing url does not exist wrongly for a particular url in R?

Tags: r, url, r-modis

I am using a [R package](http://r-gis.net/?q=ModisDownload) for downloading MODIS data.

It is giving error as

`the http address does not exist! Version may be incorrect OR Server is down!`

Interestingly version is correct, and I can excess the site which is a data repository that shows server is not down.

The URL which this R package is trying to access is 
'https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD43A3.006/'

Though the URL exist, when I check it as

```
u = 'https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD43A3.006/'
if (!url.exists(u)) print('URL does not exist')


[1] "URL does not exist"
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: `url.exists('https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD43A3.006/')` gives TRUE to me..and this doesn't print anything `if (!url.exists('https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD43A3.006/')) print('URL does not exist')`

Comment: This is wierd, it gives `FALSE` to me